# Proposition 4 of Chapter $4$ From Royden Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

From Real Analysis By Halsey Royden,

[image]

Please someone let me know,how to show

$R \underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)dx \leq sup_{\phi \leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x) dx$

I was trying using the definition given

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to understand why the lower integral is less than or equal to the supremum of Riemann integrals of dominated step functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the result you want, we first show that every lower Riemann sum (called $s$ in the textbook, is less than or equal to $\sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$. Looking at the definition of $s$, you have $s=\int_a^b \varphi(x)dx$ for some step function $\varphi$ defined such that $\varphi(x)=m_i$ on $(\xi_{i-1},\xi_i]$. It can be seen that $\varphi\leq f$, and thus
$$s=\int_a^b \varphi(x)dx\leq \sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$$
Taking supremum over $s$ you get the desired result.

Comment: We started with a arbitary partition and for that partition we showed $s \leq \sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$ But will this be valid for the $sup$  $s$?I mean if we have a set containing $s$ defined for all partition.And since we started this with arbitary partition,the above will be  valid for all elements in the set.But since  the supremum may not belong to the set,will this be vallid for the $sup$  $s$ too?

Comment: Yes, this is true (sort of intuitively). If we really want some rigorous proof, you can try to use proof by contradiction and some $\epsilon-\delta$ kind of argument to establish it. This is a good exercise to do since this "taking sup" reasoning will be used extensively as you study real analysis. If you really get stuck, feel free to ask me and I will be happy to write down the details.

Comment: I tried as : let $\epsilon >0$ suppose  $\sup s >  \sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$.....$1$   But we know that : if $p=\sup A$ iff $\forall \epsilon >0$,$\exists x \in A$ with $x>p-\epsilon$ and $x \leq p$.So $\exists  x \in s$,such that $x>\sup s - \epsilon \implies x+\epsilon > \sup s$ So,from $1$,we have $x+\epsilon>\sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$ but as $\epsilon $ tends to zero,we have $ x > \sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$ which is the contradiction to $\forall x \in s$,$s \leq \sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$  Is it correct?

Comment: Am I wrong,I need a reply on this?

Comment: Essentially correct, except that when you send $\epsilon\to 0$ in the expression $x+\epsilon>sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$ you get $x\geq sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$ instead of $x>sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$. But you can remedy this easily by writing $\sup s>c+sup_{\phi\leq f}\int_a^b \phi(x)dx$ for some $c>0$ at the beginning (think of why you can do this).